# display image from a directory and text from a text file

Tags: php

a current project of mine is giving me some trouble. The web page in question is supposed to display text from a text file followed by an accompanying image from a directory.

Currently, the output is text 1, image 1, text 2, image 1, text 1, image 2, text 2, image 2

My code so far:

```
    foreach ($DirEntries as $Entry)
    {
        if((strcmp($Entry, '.') != 0) && (strcmp($Entry, '..') != 0))
        {

            $inputFile = fopen("imagelist.txt", "r");
            if ($inputFile) 
            {
                while (($line = fgets($inputFile)) !== false) 
                {
                    echo "Name, description, and file name:<br />" . $line."<br>";
                    echo "<img src=\"files/" . $Entry . "\" ><br /><br />\n";     
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "There was an error in the opening file";
            } 
            fclose($inputFile);

        }
    }
    closedir($DirOpen);                         
    ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be the nested while loop since you're dealing with a one to one relationship.

This should solve the problem for you:

```
$inputFile = fopen("imagelist.txt", "r");

// probably better to check for file readability before looping the directory items.
if (!$inputFile) {
    echo "There was an error in the opening file";
}
else {

    foreach ($DirEntries as $entry)
    {
        if($entry === '.' || $entry === '..')
        {
            continue; // using a continue helps keeps the code indentation levels down.
        }

        // assuming that each line corresponds to an image in the same order
        if (($line = fgets($inputFile)))
        {
            echo "Name, description, and file name:<br />" . $line."<br>";
            echo "<img src=\"files/" . $entry . "\" ><br /><br />\n";     
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Image '$entry' has no metadata";
        } 
    }

    fclose($inputFile);

}
closedir($DirOpen);
```

Good luck!